Class 320 panel system one generator
I'm building a new house and am planning for the future. I am going to have a class 320 panel system so two 200A panels. What I want to do is have it set up with one backup generator like a Cummins RS50. What I want to know is if this is possible to support both panels with a large single phase generator? The other option I thought about was a 3 phase generator and doing a double Delta or Scott T transformer the problem I've been thinking about is the loads are not going to be balanced so it will put a lot of stress on the generator. Let me know what you're thinking and maybe I missed a simple solution.

Do you really need a whole house gen, or will one that can power only essential needs do?  Can have the essentials placed on one panel.  Use heat pumps for AC/heat instead of other systems that take more power for the same amount.

What are the failure scenarios that you are planning for?   What are 3 high-powered devices you intend to run on generator?

I do want a real whole house generator. We loose power quite frequently out where I am for extended periods of time. To the point I almost drilled my own gas well to have my own power generation since I'm right on a NG coal seem. I'll be running a business with several 50A breakers 240V circuits running periodically through the day. It is not really possible for me to have all essential loads on one panel as it would overload it frequently.

Have you looked at single panel Class 320 setups at all? (They do exist.)

Do you have the gas supply capacity for that beast?  Probably a 2 inch
utility supply pipe??

I have the gas supply as we have a farm running off a 5000 gallon propane tank and my supply lines to my house are 2" IPS since that is what I had lying around. @ThreePhaseEel I have not seen those I will take a look at cost of those. I'm curious how those work with the two feeds coming in.

@Stephen -- you don't need "two feeds" for Class 320 is my point

Class 320 aka 400A service is typically installed as dual 200A (48 kW) main panels, for cost reasons.   If price is NOOOOOOOO object, 400A (96 kW) industrial panelboards can be obtained.
This creates a huge complication with transfer switches, because most transfer switches and interlocks only switch 2 poles and not neutral.
Not unless the transfer switches are 3-pole and switch neutral.
What you can't do is have the generator feed split to two panels, with neutral unswitched and connecting both panels' neutrals to each other.  This creates a second, unintended path for neutral between the panels, and this can cause all matter of menace.
You may think "well it's not necessary for ALL transfer switches to be 3-pole, one of them can still be 2-pole and there won't be a loop with only one".  That is true.
The simplest solution is to concentrate all the critical loads in one panel. Then only put that panel on backup.  This tends to work better for generator sizing too, because Code requires the generator be sized to pick up the entire load to be served (minus loads which are on load shed devices). Rather than several hundred bucks a pop for a bunch of load sheds for dryer, pool, hot tub, EV charging, house auxiliary resistance heat, workshop, etc. etc. that you would never run on generator anyway, you simply place those on the panel that is not backed up.

bravo...........

Thanks. I think this answers my question. So there really is no good way to use a 3 phase generator to feed two separate panels. My best bet is to plan for using a Cummins RS100KW  with a 400A dual lug(with neutral) ATS to supply my two mains.

@Stephen yeah it's really hard to work with 3 phases in a household supply, and you'd definitely have to be switching neutral on all panels merely because their voltage would not match up.  And either all panels would drop voltage down to 208V, or one panel would need to be 240V-only.  Wow, for the kind of money you're talking I'd be seriously evaluating solar/battery systems.  Buying a generator in 2024 is like buying a steam locomotive in 1955.

I would disagree with that. Solar is great for a general 200A service with general loads but a typical 200A home solar panel system last around 15 years and cost $36,000 in my area. Yes it offsets my consumption when I have power but when I do lose power the amount of battery backup I would need would be astronomical. Let's say 6 hours a day I'm pulling 100Amps at each panel. That's 288KW so if I have a 48KW panel it essentially cut that in half if it's working perfectly. Still large. Just energy density of fossil fuels just can't be compared yet. I do have solar for a lot of things though.

@Stephen yeah that's just the same tired old naysayer talking points. #1 15 years is nonsense #2 conservation > generation, you don't rack $5000 in solar/battery just so you can keep using an obsolete 100 year old design, you buy the efficient appliance and less battery.  #3 "6 hours a day I pull 100A at each panel" is bonkers. Average US home takes 29 kWH/day without making the least effort to conserve.  But end of the day it's an emotional decision, make the choice that makes you feel safe.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica I would love to to go down the efficiency rabbit hole since the design of this house business combo was 5 years in the making ensuring it was well calculated with the principal of diminishing returns. As I've established I'm not a average household. My current consumption with old technology is around 230KW/day on average we look to cut that to180KW/day with all the new equipment and installation standards. Only real energy saver would be our dryers to heat pump dryers.

Yes, you can feed both panels with two conditions:

The ATS must be rated for the higher supply, IE the 400A one.
The anticipated loads must be within the generator capacity

With a 400A single phase ATS you can feed both panels.  The switch needs to be rated for the full combined utility load even though the generator is smaller.  The wires from the ATS to each of the two 200A panels may need to be rated for 400A, though steps can be taken to avoid that.
In a comment you said putting all essential loads on one 200A panel would "overload frequently".  If that is the case, you may not use a 200A standby generator.  A standby generator needs to handle anticipated loads.  If your plan is to manage generator loads manually that's fine but in that case you need to switch to generator manually.
And if you do that, there are easier and cheaper solutions.  Be creative.  I don't know your situation but if, for example, two or three of your high-powered machines are outdoors or against an outside wall, they could be powered separately, one at a time, during an outage with a cheap portable gasoline generator.   A few adjustments like that might allow you to arrange a critical loads panel fed by a standby generator smaller than 200A that doesn't consume commercial quantities of gas.

Those 400A ATS are extremely expensive. I was hoping I could do two 200A ATS one for each panel since they are way cheaper for two of them than one 400A. Would it be better just to have two 48KW generators at this point. I feel like we should be able to have a 3 phase generator with total output of around 100KW continuous cheaper just need to have it setup correctly.

I think a 400W ATS can be had for about $2k if you find one designed for single-phase only.  I looked at that before suggesting it.   The generator is about $20k, the whole project will be about 30, and you're talking about drilling your own gas so I figured $2k was in range!      You could use two 200A ATSs, one per panel if you make them subs of a new main panel with two 200A breakers after the meter.   The generator could feed them both.   I don't know if the signaling would work, and I doubt it.  They can't both control the generator. So no.  I could be wrong.

My suggestion:  Get a new 100A panel, move all your truly critical things there.  Some lights, refrigerators, sewage pumps, some heating, anything safety-related.  Cap it at 15kW or so.  None of your business equipment.  Get a 15kW or so standby generator and ATS for that panel.  That new panel, and your two existing ones, all become subs of another new panel, your new "meter main", with two 200A breakers and a 60A one for the new sub.   Only the new sub is on ATS, and only 15kW.  [ ... 1/ 2 ]

[ ... 2/2] Put interlocks on the other two panels and get a couple of 15kW portable generators for those that you roll out when needed during business hours.  The whole project could come in under $20K and outside business hours you're only running a small 15kW generator.  You have the option of running them on two or three different fuels if that works better for you.  IE if you don't have gas service now for the huge Cummins, run one or both of the portables on gasoline.  This plan also avoids spooking your utility and Buildings ppl with non-residential kit.

Key question is: Will the two 200A panels will be near each other?
If they are, which is quite common, then make one the generate backed-up "critical loads" panel. Split something like this:
Critical Loads (generator backup)

Refrigerators/freezers
Internet
At least a couple of general purpose circuits for receptacles and lighting.
At least one kitchen countertop circuit
Microwave oven (unless on that same kitchen countertop circuit) - that lets you heat up food with short bursts of 1500W instead of the potentially much higher loads of an oven or cooktop
HVAC - ideally heat pumps as they can take care of H and AC.

Other Panel (no backup)

EV Charging
Water Heater - generally not critical, plus (assuming you don't to tankless, but no way you're running tankless on a generator anyway) for a short outage you will have hot water as long as you tell everyone to hold off on hot showers/baths
Clothes Dryer
Electric Oven and Cooktop

And one more key issue:
Load Calculation
Some people get Class 320 because they want to plan for the future, which is OK. But most people don't actually need 320A continuous/400A total. A proper NEC Load Calculation will determine what you really need. If your Load Calculation works out to 250A, for example, then your generator needs to be sized for 250A, not 320A or 400A. Your actual usage will be far below the Load Calculation most of the time, but it gives you a workable upper limit.
And please, please, please - do NOT get tankless electric hot water for the whole house. A single tankless system can easily use 120A all by itself, so it significantly affects Load Calculation and generator requirements.
Last, you may be able to do a little better with load sharing/shedding. If you have major production equipment that must run, so be it. But EV charging, tanked water heating and sometimes other loads can be turned off automatically when usage gets too high overall. That can make the difference between 200A and 320A/400A service in some cases. But more importantly here, it can make a big difference in generator requirements for a whole house backup.

The panels will be wired right next to each other. I will have essential loads on both. See my comments to the above comments. I also can get a larger 90KVA 3 phase generator cheaper than I can get a single phase RS50.

@Stephen I'm leaving my answer up as I think it is useful advice for many similar but not exactly the same situations.

Totally agree. Great advice in general. Especially the tankless comment and people who don't do a true load calculation always end up oversizing. Luckily for me I use a boiler for hot water and home heating. There are tankless propane as well and they are much better than tankless electric.
